# Java FX changing value of Label from different scene

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8, fxml

I have two scenes. The first scene invokes second scene using the following code.

```
@FXML
private void confirmation(ActionEvent event) throws IOException{
 Stage confirmation_stage;
 Parent confirmation;
 confirmation_stage=new Stage();
 confirmation=FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Confirmation.fxml"));
 confirmation_stage.setScene(new Scene(confirmation));
 confirmation_stage.initOwner(generate_button.getScene().getWindow());
 confirmation_stage.show();
 }
```

There is a label in "Confirmation.fxml" called "Proceed".

I need to change the content of that label from within this function and return the result(true/false). Help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a `ConfirmationController` for the FXML. From the controller, expose a method which allows you to pass data (string) to set to the label.

```
public class ConfirmationController implements Initializable {

    ...
    @FXML
    private Label proceed;
    ...
    public void setTextToLabel (String text) {
         proceed.setText(text);
    }
    ...
}
```

Inside your method where you are loading the FXML, you can have :

```
...
FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("Confirmation.fxml"));
confirmation = loader.load();
ConfirmationController controller = (ConfirmationController)loader.getController();
controller.setTextToLabel("Your Text"); // Call the method we wrote before
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Labels in FXML have a *setText* method. So for your case the "Proceed" label will look something like:

```
Proceed.setText("The new text");
```

As for the second part of the question, I'm not 100% sure as to what you are asking. I don't really see any case for the function to return true or false.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have a controller called:`confirmation_controller.java'.` inside that controller, you have a public method `getProceedLabel()` that returns a reference for the label called `Proceed`. you can try the following code:

```
 Stage confirmation_stage;
 Parent confirmation;
 confirmation_stage=new Stage();
 FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("Confirmation.fxml"));
 confirmation = loader.load();
 confirmation_controller controller = loader.getController();
 Label label = controller.getProceedLabel();
 label.setText("..."):
 confirmation_stage.setScene(new Scene(confirmation));
 confirmation_stage.initOwner(generate_button.getScene().getWindow());
 confirmation_stage.show();
```

Comment: This is a really horrible idea, though. Exposing UI controls from a controller breaks encapsulation under every possible interpretation. There is really no point in separating the view and logic in the first place (the basic point of FXML and controller classes) if you are then going to expose the UI details outside of the controller class. The application should share *data*, not the UI components.