# How can I use .setText on a non-Static Label from a different Class

Tags: javafx, label, fxml, settext, non-static

Hy,

I want to set in JavaFX a Label Text from a second Controller.

I have a stage called GUI.fxml and a Controller_GUI.java and i have a stage called Login.fxml and a Controller_Login.java.

At the GUI screen I open the Login screen and put I data in click the login button. then the Controller_Login make the Login. After that at the GUI.xml I want to change a Label text to "Connected" but its controlled from Controller_GUI.java and the Label has to be called non-static, the other way it will not set the Label and I will get a "Null" error message.

Is there a way to bypass this or a nice tricky solution to get the Label text setted?

GUI.xml

```
<Label fx:id="labelConnected" contentDisplay="CENTER" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="20.0" text="Disconnected" />
```

Controller_Login.java

```
    public void buttonLoginGuiLogin(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
    if (GUI.Login_Interface.Login(textfieldLoginGuiEMail.getText(),textfieldLoginGuiPassword.getText())) {
        // set the label text
        ((Node)(event.getSource())).getScene().getWindow().hide();
    }
    else {
        labelLoginMessage.setText("Wrong E-Mail or Password.");
    }
}
```

Controller_GUI.java

```
@FXML public Label labelConnected;
```

Comment: see [this -the correct answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31083113/java-fx-changing-value-of-label-from-different-scene/31084877#31084877).

Comment: thanks fabian this fixed it.